# Is posible show if openstack is overcommitting memory in a virtual machine only from OS?

Tags: memory, openstack, heap-memory, ram, memory-overcommitment

How could I know from Operating System in a Virtual Machine if ram memory is being overcommited by Openstack hypervisor?

My app is being killed by the operating system cause Out of Memory error, but I have configured the heap and meta space under 70% of the total available ram.

I have no access to the openstack configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot know the details of OpenStack overcommit if you do not have access to the OpenStack configuration or environment directly (root/admin privileges).

Your VM is seen as a "standalone" server/node to itself and you therefore you will need to request this information from whoever is hosting/operating the OpenStack install.

Comment: But what if i try to execute a process with full ram consumption? Is there some way to do that? I know that i should do this in all my servers at the same time.

Comment: You can execute a process with full RAM but that does not mean you will be able to find out if OpenStack is configured to overcommit. Overcommit is not about giving your VM more RAM than what is visible. I suggest you read the following for information about what overcommit is for - https://docs.openstack.org/arch-design/design-compute/design-compute-overcommit.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access of compute nodes , then you can check nova.conf file with param `ram_allocation_ratio` , else there is no way to find the info you are looking for until you have the access of compute nodes.

Comment: I have not. Any way my problem was solved detecting what system process was consuming memory. It was a bug of dhclient.